# I want to bypass my emails from a proxy server in Suite CRM Email Client

Tags: proxy, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm, proxy-server

I want to send email from suitecrm throw my proxy server . i checked the checkbox in system settings "use proxy server", and entered proxy host, port, username and password . but can't send emails .